# Import data from SQL Server into Excel does not import keys

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, excel-2010

I'm trying to import a SQL Server 2008 R2 table into Excel.

Everything works fine except that the primary key and foreign keys from the specific table aren't imported.

Can anyone point out what could be the problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by *not imported*? The values from those columns don't show up? Or did you expect to get a primary key constraint inside Excel? Also: can you show us ***how*** you import that data? Are you using SSIS? Some custom code of your own? You need to **show us!** We cannot read your screen nor your mind.....

Comment: In excel I use the wizard dataconnection and use other sources, from sql server.

Comment: After that I use windows credentials to the server which all work fine, I select the database and select the table I wish to see, after that I push button 'Next' and Finish.

Connection string:
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=sql01\Columbus;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=WS26;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=Columbus

Command text: "Columbus"."dbo"."Sheets"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed my problem.
Apparently, when I am using MSQuery from Excel 2010, instead of the Data Connection wizard for SQL Server, I am able to select all Columns. 
This way I do get everything in excel.

thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Cast your key as a varchar before passing it in to Excel.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to select the table after `SELECT * FROM table` in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), mark the whole table result and copy-paste to the excel sheet?

Comment: Yes I tried that, in that case it does work, but I do not want to log into my SQL server because its part of weekly reporting.